# virtual machine doesn't use allocated disk space

Tags: mount, virtualbox, virtual-machine, manjaro, oracle-vm-server

I am running manjaro in an Oracle VirtualBox to test a virgin install of a set of softwares. I am getting an error that there is no more disk space on a particular download, however, when I set up the vm in the VirtualBox Manager, I am allocating it plenty of space (> 100GB). I have tried changing this from dynamic allocation to a fixed partition, but this did not solve the issue.

When I run `lsblk`, this is the output:

```
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0   7:0    0 130.6M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/livefs
loop1   7:1    0 581.9M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/mhwdfs
loop2   7:2    0   1.5G  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/desktopfs
loop3   7:3    0 702.8M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/rootfs
sda     8:0    0   134G  0 disk 
sr0    11:0    1   2.9G  0 rom  /run/miso/bootmnt
```

So to me it looks like the 134gb partition needs to be mounted?

I run `sudo fdisk -l` to see where it is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 134.01 GiB, 143895691264 bytes, 281046272 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 130.6 MiB, 136945664 bytes, 267472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 581.94 MiB, 610209792 bytes, 1191816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 1.47 GiB, 1582903296 bytes, 3091608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 702.77 MiB, 736907264 bytes, 1439272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I am running the installs from my $HOME directory (which in this case is `/home/manjaro`), so I try `sudo mount /dev/sda /home/manjaro`, and this is the output:

```
mount: /home/manjaro: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev             5.3G     0  5.3G   0% /dev
run             5.3G  114M  5.2G   3% /run
/dev/sr0        3.0G  3.0G     0 100% /run/miso/bootmnt
cowspace        256M     0  256M   0% /run/miso/cowspace
overlay_root    7.9G   79M  7.9G   1% /run/miso/overlay_root
/dev/loop0      131M  131M     0 100% /run/miso/sfs/livefs
/dev/loop1      582M  582M     0 100% /run/miso/sfs/mhwdfs
/dev/loop2      1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /run/miso/sfs/desktopfs
/dev/loop3      703M  703M     0 100% /run/miso/sfs/rootfs
overlay         7.9G   79M  7.9G   1% /
tmpfs           5.3G     0  5.3G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3G   53M  5.3G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           5.3G  2.4M  5.3G   1% /etc/pacman.d/gnupg
tmpfs           1.1G  104K  1.1G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Output of `mount`:

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=5480388k,nr_inodes=1370097,mode=755,inode64)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/sr0 on /run/miso/bootmnt type iso9660 (ro,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8)
cowspace on /run/miso/cowspace type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=262144k,mode=755,inode64)
overlay_root on /run/miso/overlay_root type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=8264028k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/loop0 on /run/miso/sfs/livefs type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/dev/loop1 on /run/miso/sfs/mhwdfs type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/dev/loop2 on /run/miso/sfs/desktopfs type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/dev/loop3 on /run/miso/sfs/rootfs type squashfs (ro,relatime)
overlay on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/run/miso/sfs/livefs:/run/miso/sfs/mhwdfs:/run/miso/sfs/desktopfs:/run/miso/sfs/rootfs,upperdir=/run/miso/overlay_root/upper,workdir=/run/miso/overlay_root/work,index=off,xino=off)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=12054)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=5509352k,nr_inodes=409600,inode64)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /etc/pacman.d/gnupg type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1101868k,nr_inodes=275467,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Output of `losetup`:

```
NAME    SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                                    DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop1
                0      0         0  1 /run/miso/bootmnt/manjaro/x86_64/mhwdfs.sfs    0     512
/dev/loop2
                0      0         0  1 /run/miso/bootmnt/manjaro/x86_64/desktopfs.sfs
                                                                                     0     512
/dev/loop0
                0      0         0  1 /run/miso/bootmnt/manjaro/x86_64/livefs.sfs    0     512
/dev/loop3
                0      0         0  1 /run/miso/bootmnt/manjaro/x86_64/rootfs.sfs    0     512
```

Let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of `df -h` and `mount`. Did you create a partition on `sda`? `fdisk` says otherwise

Comment: I edited to include those outputs (see above). I have not done anything besides launching the vm through oracle virtualbox. Do I need to create a partition?

Comment: Please, add `losetup` output (without parameters, I want to see the loop devices backing store). Currently, the system looks like it booted from a DVD (`sr0`). Hard disk (`sda`) doesn't seem to be partitioned and used in any way. So it is expected for it to not havin any file system and therefore not being mountable. Are you sure you had installed something onto it?

Comment: Strictly you don't need a partition to `mount`, you need a filesystem. A partition [may still be the right thing anyway](https://superuser.com/a/1181406/432690).

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I added the output to losetup above. Yes it looks like the storage I'm trying to assign to the vm is being booted as a separate disk. What I want is for this space to be available when I'm working from my $HOME directory, which right now only gets ~ 7GB. I don't understand why it's configured this way.

Comment: The system runs from DVD, now it's for sure, because `/run/miso/bootmnt` is mounted from `sr0` and all loop devices are backed by squashfs files located on that removable device. I suppose 7 GB is the available RAM in the VM (check e.g. `top` what's listed under `avail`), which is used as a *ramdisk overlay* to the otherwire read-only squashfs.

Comment: Gotcha, is there any way I can get the system to have access to more storage from the other drive?

Comment: Partition it, mount and use. Are you planning to always run it from DVD?

Comment: I'm not intentionally running it that way, it's just what oracle vm virtualbox did when I assigned it storage. As mentioned above I got an error when I tried to mount it. Am I not doing it correctly?

Comment: You have to create a file system, and preferable partition and create it on a partition. Notice you'll be in the need to mount it again each time you boot from a removable. But I suggest you to *install* a system inside of a VM on that virtual HDD, and then remove the DVD and use VM as if it was a computer. This is how people use it.

Comment: I ran `fdisk /dev/sda':

`
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.37.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x58c167db.

Command: s

The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
`
Then I ran `sudo mount /dev/sda /home/manjaro`:

`
mount: /home/manjaro: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

`

Comment: So I'm still seeing the same error as above

Comment: I had to run `mkfs` on /dev/sda then mount. It wiped my home directory but at least it had the required space

Comment: This is not a viable solution. When the home directory is wiped and mounted, now all files are read-only, and none of my programs work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work by mounting the drive in a separate directory inside the home directory. To test the installs, I had to put everything inside this mounted directory, else I didn't have access to the space. So this is not a perfect fix, but was fine just to test some installs. To summarize:

- Made an empty directory in $HOME called `mnt`
- Ran `fdisk` on the drive (`/dev/sda` in this case)
- Ran `mkfs` on the drive
- Ran `mount [drive] [destination]` (`mount /dev/sda $HOME/mnt` in this case)

After this, the `mnt` folder had access to the space on the drive. Not the cleanest fix, but worked well enough for my purposes.